# model.count not a reliable test of existence for fast asynchronous writes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

Before saving a new document to a mongodb collection via nodejs in my MongoLab database, I'm using model.count to check certain fields to prevent a duplicate entry:

```
MyModel.count({field1: criteria1, field2: criteria2}, function (err, count) {
  if (count == 0) {
    // Create new document and call .save()
  }
});
```

However, during testing I'm noticing many duplicates (inconsistent in number across test runs) in the collection after the process finishes, although not as many as if I did not do the .count() check.

Since the `MyModel.count()` statement is embedded in a callback being repeatedly called whenever the `'readable'` event is emitted by one of several ReadStreams, I suspect there is an async issue caused by rapid writes to the collection. Specifically, two or more identical and nearly simultaneous calls to `MyModel.count` return a `count` of `0`, and end up each creating and saving (identical) documents to the collection.

Does this sound probable? And if so how can I enforce uniqueness of document writes without setting timeouts or using a synchronous pattern?

Comment: Have you explored using a unique index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter commented, the right way to enforce uniqueness is to create a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the collection over those fields and then handle the `code: 11000` insert error to recover from attempts at creating duplicates.

You can add the index via your schema before you create the model from it:

```
mySchema.index({field1: 1, field2: 1}, {unique: true});
```